I can't get my laptop to connect with my monitor ever since I tried to connect to a hotel TV
I have an original Microsoft Surface laptop. I use a mini-display port-to-HDMI cord to connect it to monitors and TVs. Up until now I have had no problems connecting it to other displays. On TVs I will duplicate it and on my monitor, I will extend it.
I recently tried to connect it to a hotel TV. The TV would appear to connect and then would display "No signal". I tried all of the HDMI ports on the TV to no avail.
So now that I am home, I am trying to connect the laptop to my monitor like usual and it won't work. When I connect the new screen, the little indicator light on the monitor goes from orange to white, but then it goes back to orange and says, "Going into power save mode". When I check the "Display" settings while plugged in, it says that my laptop can see the other monitor. When I open apps, it is even clear that they are opening on the other screen, but my monitor is still black.
Any ideas what could be the problem?

There are two possibilities:

The hardware in the tablet or the Mini DisplayPort to HDMI cable was damaged.
The software (including Registry settings, drivers and operating system) have issues.

To test which is the case, before trying repairs, boot the Surface device from USB. There is no need to install anything on the device.

Create bootable media, such as a USB drive with Linux (e.g., Live Ubuntu) or Hiren's BootCD PE.
Shut the laptop completely (e.g., using shutdown /s /t 0).
Plug in the USB drive.
Press and hold the Volume-Down, and with the button held, press and release the Power button.
Keep Volume-Down held until dots are shown beneath the MS Surface logo.
Follow on-screen instructions to continue USB boot.

If the Surface laptop can connect to an external HDMI display when booted from USB, then it's a software issue. Try various Windows trouble-shooters, reinstall drivers, etc.
If it cannot connect to an external HDMI display, then hardware is damaged. In that case, the most likely cause is a bad Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter, which are available for US$10 or less at Amazon, Best Buy or elsewhere. If you cannot test another adapter cable, it might be cheaper to buy one than to take the laptop in for testing and repairs.
However, if the Mini DisplayPort on the Surface has been damaged, repair would likely be pricey.
As to what might cause damage to the cable or Mini DisplayPort, static electricity (ESD) (despite built-in ESD protection) or miswired AC outlets could possibly destroy components. Bent connector pins or a physically damaged cable could also cause the issue.

Thank you! I am guessing the cable is damaged. These cheap eBay cables only last so long. I will try a new cable.
